# PHP: Do I need to check if $_SESSION exists before I attempt to destroy it?

Tags: php

EDIT: Sorry about the title- I meant "before I attempt to unset it".

I want to destroy a specific session cookie, so I do so like:

```
unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

...but the user may or may not have that session set. So, should I be checking to see if it exists first, or does `unset()` take care of that for me without errors?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {

  unset($_SESSION['name']);

}
```

Comment: wouldent testing answer that?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Its always good to check if key exist in array, otherwise you'll get E_NOTICE in your logs.

Comment: How is this question getting up-votes.. you simply need to look at the [PHP Manual for `unset()`](http://php.net/unset), or test it.

Comment: @Dagon I tried testing it, and I did not see any errors, but I don't know if that's because I missed something, due to my current configuration, or what, so I want to be sure it's okay everywhere- not just on my machine.

Comment: no php version seems to care it does not exist: https://3v4l.org/WmE2H

Comment: That is what I answered. You would get no error using either one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesn't matter whether you had to check it.Because whether you check it,the session will be unset and the unset function won't return any error.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @pableiros How is this not an answer?

Comment: Actually we both have the same answer so +1. If we read the question correctly, we get what @JROB want's to know

Comment: @Paulpro you said: "I think it doesn't matter..." it's a thought not a fact.